# How to restyle tab control in WPF

Tags: wpf, styles, tabcontrol

i search google for restyling tab control in WPF and i found many but i am not getting any sample according to my requirement. here i am attaching the picture of the tab control which looks good.

[image]

i want to have the same look tab control in WPF so please some one guide me how to do it.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [`AvalonDock`](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex. It has similar style for `TabControl`. You can go ahead and use that or look into code and try it yourself.

[image]

Comment: thanks for ur answer...how to extract the tab portion from avalon dock project. looking for ur suggestion

Comment: Download source code from CodePlex and look for that control's style. You should find it. You can also use Blend to extract styles.

Comment: how expression blend can be use to extract style. please discuss in detail. i am wpf beginner.

Comment: a lot of articles are there: http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2010/01/19/extract-styles-in-expression-blend.aspx and search the web: http://www.bing.com/search?q=extract+style+expression+blend&go=&form=QBRE&qs=n&sk=

Answer (score 3):

Check if this helps

[How to create trapezoid tabs in WPF tab control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/561931/217880)