# Adding Tab Capibilities to a Basic Text Editor

Tags: wpf, tabs, text-editor, notepad++

I currently have created a basic text editor in `windows wpf`. I was wondering if there was a way to add tabs (simmilar to notepad++ tabs). Right now I use a `richTextBox` that the user enters in the text. I want to let the user open new tabs in the notepad editor. I've found an example: [How to create trapezoid tabs in WPF tab control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561931/how-to-create-trapezoid-tabs-in-wpf-tab-control).  but its a little more advanced for me. If anyone has any starting point suggestions or know any basic examples it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF TabControl is what you need. Using it you can easily add a new TabItem as child to the tabcontrol and insert a RichTextEditor as content to the TabItem.

The link you include is however merely describing how to re-style a tabcontrol.

The real issue for you will be developing an application with multiple open documents.