# WPF TabItem Style - Redraw tab after changing header text

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have used the excellent post [How to create trapezoid tabs in WPF tab control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561931/how-to-create-trapezoid-tabs-in-wpf-tab-control) in order to make my own TabControl.

I'm trying to figure how to change the tab width calculation after changing the header text??
I begin with a header text of "New Group", after the user enter text in some TextBox I want that text to appear in the Header, but now the TabItem width is not right for the new text.

How to recalculate the width ???

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 
I didn't find any solution so I did it quite dirty.
I just did that

```
TabItem.Style = null;
TabItem .Style = (Style)FindResource("Tabitem112");
```

So basically, I just dropped the style and re-applied it.
It's working. 
I'd like to see a more professional approach.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [this style](http://www.wpfblogger.com/post/BreadCrumb-TabControl-Style-for-WPF-40.aspx). It recalculates the header width to fit the name.